# How do I join a subrecord in a netsuite Advanced template for a sales order?

Tags: html, netsuite

I'm trying to build a template for a packing slip list for a Netsuite Sales Order. This template needs access to the Country of Origin on the inventory details for the fulfillment item.

I've been using the [netsuite records viewer](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_1/script/record/item.html).

As I understand it, a "Sales Order" has Items. Items have "Inventory Details".

According to the docs, it looks like in order to link an item and inventory details you need to do a join.

I'm brand new to netsuite and finding data has been a challenge. If I go to the item fulfillment record in netsuite I see the "inventory detail" column. I click on the icon to bring up the inventory details. I then click on the "serial/lot" number and I am presented with the data I'm looking for in the "Country of Origin" section.

If I click on that, it tells me the fieldId is "custitemnumber_cnt_country_of_origin"

I've tried every instance of this I can imagine but I'm completely stumped on what the parent of this is.

In the template I've tried:

```
${custitemnumber_cnt_country_of_origin}
${itemnumber.custitemnumber_cnt_country_of_origin}
${tranline.itemnumber.custitemnumber_cnt_country_of_origin}
(tranline in this case is salesorder.item as tranline)
```

All I'm looking to do is display the Country of Origin in this table via the template:

```
<#list salesorder.item as tranline><tr>
    <td colspan="12"><span class="itemname"><DISPLAY COO HERE></td>
    <td colspan="3">${tranline.custcol_mr_po_line_no}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4" style="width: 72px;">${tranline.quantityordered}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4" style="width: 84px;">${tranline.quantityremaining}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4" style="width: 79px;">${tranline.quantity}</td>
    </tr>
</#list>
```

Comment: So you're doing the following
Sales Order-->Item Fulfillment-->Inventory Detail-->Field, correct?

Comment: Yes that's exactly correct @Jdg50

Answer (score 0):

It may be a different ID. Try Opening a Sales Order Saved Search and adding a Formula (text) filter. It should open the formula creator (see image). Use the Field Drop down to find your desired field and it will populate the field ID in the Formula box. [formula creator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twD2o.png)